# Terminal, Exit status aligned to right

Tags: bash, terminal, prompt

I'm composing my personal prompt for bash and i would like to add the exit status of the previous command at the end of the prompt line.

For example

```
goofy@disney:~$ test "0" = "0"
goofy@disney:~$ test "0" = "1"                         ✔️0
goofy@disney:~$                                        ✘1
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar Good to know this, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

try this 
`\$?`

Demo :

```
$PS1="\$?:>"
0:>test "0" = "1"
1:>test "0" = "0"
0:>test "0" = "1"
1:>
```

Answer (score 1):

See this simple example:

```
bash# cat rc
PS1="pynexj@so # \[\e[s\e[\$(( COLUMNS - 4 ))GE\$?\e[u\]"
bash# source ./rc 
pynexj@so # false                                          E0
pynexj@so # true                                           E1
pynexj@so # (exit 127)                                     E0
pynexj@so # true                                           E127
pynexj@so #                                                E0
```

A bit explanation:

- `ESC [ s` - save current cursor position
- `ESC [`*N*`G` - move cursor to column *N*
- `ESC [ u` - restore saved cursor position

See [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for more details.